# Python Matplotlib callback function with parameters

Tags: python, button, matplotlib, callback

In a callback function of button presses, is there anyway to pass more parameters other than 'event'? For example, in the call back function, I want to know the text of the button ('Next' in this case). How can I do that?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

fig = plt.figure()
def next(event):
    # I want to print the text label of the button here, which is 'Next'
    pass


axnext = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
bnext = Button(axnext, 'Next')
bnext.on_clicked(next)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To obtain that, you might need to encapsulate event processing in a class, as in [official tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

class ButtonClickProcessor(object):
    def __init__(self, axes, label):
        self.button = Button(axes, label)
        self.button.on_clicked(self.process)

    def process(self, event):
        print self.button.label

fig = plt.figure()

axnext = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
bnext = ButtonClickProcessor(axnext, "Next")

plt.show()
```

Comment: This worked well for me, but lacked an obvious way of calling an external object's function. For anyone trying to add a button to a plot inside a larger data structure, here's another tip. I was stuck trying to get myObject.function() to be called inside process. The easy way is to pass the object to init as an argument and add a line in __init__ like this:
def __init__(self, axes, label,someObject):
    self.localCopy=someObject
    ....

Answer (score 9):

Another possibly quicker solution is to use a lambda function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

fig = plt.figure()
def next(event, text):
    print(text)
    pass


axnext = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
bnext = Button(axnext, 'Next')
bnext.on_clicked(lambda x: next(x, bnext.label.get_text()))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Quick, simple and objective. Could be accepted answer